# how can set a color to a row of gridview when link button is clicked

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a gridview in my page. grid has one linkbutton. how can set a color to a row of gridview when linkbutton is clicked?

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="Options" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerfont">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="headerfontnew">

                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkView" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("rm_rights").ToString() == "1" ? "True": "False") %>' Enabled="true" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);"/>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkInsert" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("rm_rights").ToString() == "2" ? "True": "False") %>' Enabled="true" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkUpdate" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("rm_rights").ToString() == "3" ? "True": "False") %>' Enabled="true" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);"/>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkDelete" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("rm_rights").ToString() == "4" ? "True": "False") %>' Enabled="true" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);"/>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="Child" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("menu_id")%>' runat="server" >

                        <img id="ChildMenu" src="images/image_viewer.png" class="Gridimage" title="View Childs" runat="server"   ></img></asp:LinkButton>

                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerfont"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: We need some code... more information...

Comment: without the html code we are unable to help you? also you are using jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

if the link is inside a td, get to the row (parent) and change its color, something like this

```
$('#linkbutton').parent().css('background-color', '#F00');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do it:

1) On the server in code-behind. In the click event of the button, assuming the index of the row that you want to set its color is 5, and you want to set it to red:

```
void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    myGrid.Rows[5].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

2) On the user's computer (i.e. client-side) using JavaScript. You need to access the row using its id, so use its ClientID property:

```
<asp:LinkButton ........ OnClientClick="HighlightRow()" />

<script>
function HighlightRow() {
    document.getElementById("<%=myGrid.Rows[5].ClientID%>").style.background = "red";
}
</script>
```